# bbcode or ritch text editor, just need one that really works

Tags: php, javascript, bbcode, text-editor

i need something to allow users to easily insert, images, youtube videos and code, in to their posts, i tried tinymce, i manage to do all of them with it but it has a small problem, every time i load a article to be edited, the code will always disappear from it, because tinymce deletes all the tags, keyword, everything that is a code, and that makes it impossible for users to edit their posts, i tried to fix that problem but failed, tried 3 days  and finnaly i gave up, after i tried to find something else, i saw that users can do that easily on forums using bbcodes , i would like to implement something like that then, but failed to find a bbcode implementation that has img, youtube, code, tags, do you guys know any bbcode (php classes, plugins, whatever i don't know how to call it, sorry) or some text editors that can offer these features? are there any bbcode system like in the forums that i could implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free Markup BBCode Editor in Javascript: http://corpocrat.com/2008/08/15/free-wysiwyg-bbcode-editor-in-javascript/

Offline BBCode Editor: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic6161.html

BBcode editor: PHP: http://www.iceteks.com/articles.php/javascript2/1

Free BBCode Editor: http://softzilla.blogspot.com/2009/09/free-bbcode-editor.html